# Is it possible for Nations to fail in recognizing a Prophet

Tags: tanach, nevua-prophecy

Does the Tanach contain stories of the past nations who failed to identify a true Prophet whom God sent and what were the reasons given by those people to reject that true Prophet of God?

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not. When peoples are  criticized in Tanach, it's for bad behaviors, not for not accepting people who claim to be prophets.

With the exception of [Bil'am](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balaam), whom no one was criticized for ignoring, the only prophets described in Tanach are within the Jewish Nation. There aren't stories of other peoples getting their own prophets to hear from, much less ignore.

Comment: Are you sure? We have a number of stories of people ignoring true prophets in favor of fake ones. Elisha and yirmiyahu cone to mind.

Comment: I think there are two categories -- rejected prophets and rejected prophecies. There are instances where false prophets told the people what they wanted to hear so they were accepted, and others who told people what they didn't so their words were rejected. Does this mean that their status as prophet was denied?

Comment: @Dan I think there was a story of Yonah before his sefer was actually written - mentioned in Pirkey dRabbi Eliezer, where they castigated him as a false prophet because a bad prophecy relayed through him was canceled because of people's teshuvah.

Comment: So, Bil'am is the only non jewish prophet?

Comment: @JimThio http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57484/759

Comment: And somebody must have prayed for end of prophecy in Israel too. I saw no prophet anywhere on any nation now.