# The End of Prophecy amongst the Nations

Tags: gentiles, midrash, moshe-rabbeinu, nevua-prophecy, bilam

There is a medrash that after the story with Bilaam attempting to curse the Jewish people and instigating the incident with the Midianites and Baal Peor, Moshe prayed that there never again be prophecy amongst the nations. Where is this medrash?

Comment: Can you support your claim that the _midrash_ exists?

Comment: @msh210 If I could, I wouldn't have asked the question;)

Comment: @msh210 If you think I'm misremembering e.g. Vayikra Rabba 1:10 (as suggested by @Shusha) I'd consider that a possible answer...

Comment: I had no such thought. I merely was hoping that your indicating where you'd seen the _midrash_ might have helped someone find you the answer.

Comment: @loewian That's not true. You may have heard it from a respected rabbi and not known where it was found. Or seen it in a published recent work that didn't cite sources;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that this what you're looking for, but the Gmara in Baba Batra on daf 15 writes:

בתר דשכיב משה מי שריא שכינה על עובדי כוכבים 
והא אמר מר ביקש משה שלא תשרה שכינה על עובדי כוכבים וניתן לו, 
שנאמר: "ונפלינו אני ועמך".

Although it doesn't specify that this was a result of Bilaam but rather a request to make Israel more unique. This Gmara is more detailed in Brachot 7a:

וא"ר יוחנן משום ר' יוסי שלושה דברים ביקש משה מלפני הקב"ה ונתן לו, 
ביקש שתשרה שכינה על ישראל ונתן לו, 
שנאמר: "הלא בלכתך עמנו", 
ביקש שלא תשרה שכינה על עכו"ם ונתן לו, 
שנאמר: "ונפלינו אני ועמך", 
ביקש להודיעו דרכיו של הקב"ה ונתן לו, 
שנאמר: "הודיעני נא את דרכיך".

And in סדר עולם רבה (the end of chapter 21):

בלעם ואביו ואיוב מארץ עוץ ואליפז התימני ובלדד השוחי וצופר הנעמתי ואליהוא בן ברכאל הבוזי אלו הנביאים שנתנבאו לאומות עד שלא ניתנה התורה לישראל, 
אבל משניתנה תורה לישראל פסקה רוח הקודש מן האומות. 
וכן במשה הוא אומר: "ובמה יודע אפוא כי מצאתי חן בעיניך וגו' ". 
מנין שעשה הקב"ה רצונו? 
שנאמר: "הנה אנכי כורת ברית וגו' " - באותה שעה פסקה רוח הקודש מן האומות.

I hope this is what you were looking for.